# Difference between jquery $('#my_id') and document.getElementById('my_id')?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tought $('#my_id1') was the same thing as document.getElementById('my_id1'). But it is parently not. What is the difference?

```
(function( $ ) {
  $.fn.simple_hide_function = function() {
  var $t = this;
  $t.hide();
  };
})( jQuery );

$(window).load(function () {
var $div1 = $('#my_id1');
var $div2 = document.getElementById('my_id2');
$div1.simple_hide_function(); // this is working
$div2.simple_hide_function(); // but this is not working
});
```

**Adding example to make it more clear:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>

<div id="my_id1" style="height:100px;background:#f00">div1</div>
<div id="my_id2" style="height:100px;background:#f00">div2</div>



<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

(function( $ ) {
  $.fn.simple_hide_function = function() {
  var $t = this;
  $t.hide();
  };
})( jQuery );

$(window).load(function () {
var $div1 = $('#my_id1');
var $div2 = document.getElementById('my_id2');
$div1.simple_hide_function();
$div2.simple_hide_function();
});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have my_id1 vs my_id2 - identifiers are not the same

Comment: do you have div with "my_id2" id..!

Comment: Starting your variable names with $ is a bit weird - $t, $div1 and so on - just because jQuery uses $ everywhere doesn't mean you have to. Oh, you think its PHP?

Comment: @Spacedman it's a common convention to keep track of things that are supposed to be saved jQuery lookups.

Comment: thanks - not seen that before!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first returns a jQuery object with that div as its only member. You can use jQuery functions on the object to manipulate it.

The second returns a DOMElement using the browser's built-in methods.

Answer (score 7):

Difference is that first one returns a *jquery object* while the second returns a *DOM element*.

But these statements are **equivalent**:

```
document.getElementById('my_id2') <->  $('#my_id1').get(0)
```

or

```
document.getElementById('my_id2') <->  $('#my_id1')[0]
```

Comment: Not necessarily the same. Internet Explorer will return elements whose "name" attribute matches the requested "id" value from "getElementById()", but the jQuery library will never do that.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#my_id1') // Returns a jQuery object
```

And

```
getElementById('my_id1') // Returns a DOM object.
```

To get the DOM object of a jQuery object, you can call:

```
$('#my_id1').get()
```

jQuery can match more than one object with a selector, so to get the second matching DOM element:

```
$('#my_id1').get(1) // 1 = item #2 (zero-based index)
```

And to get matching DOM elements from the ***END*** of the collection, you can use a negative number, the distance from the end of the matched elements you want to retrieve, so -1 gets the last item.

```
$('#my_id1').get(-1) // gets the last item of the matched elements
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `my_id1`:

```
var $div2 = document.getElementById('my_id1');
```

Answer (score 0):

According to me, there is difference in its rendering in Browsers.

As if we do not use document. This will not work in IE browsers.

But only work in other browsers.